# UnsatisfiedLinkError, but library is in path

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm a little confused by this error. I'm new to Java and the error seems pretty self explanatory, but I've checked my paths (even defined my own) and it still fails to find this library. Is there something I'm doing wrong? See directory screenshot and error screenshot below:

[image: compiler error]
[image: directory]

**UPDATE**

[image: new error]

**UPDATE 2**

If I create a new NetBeans project this works fine. Same code and everything. If I create new IntelliJ project I get this error above. I must be missing something in IntelliJ

**UPDATE 3**

Found the solution. Adding dependencies is a bit different in IntelliJ. Thanks all for the help.

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html

Comment: Unless there's a good reason, you might want to use an IDE to run your programs. Why are you running them from the terminal if you are using intelliJ?

Comment: @sushain97 I'm not, I just took a picture of the terminal output in the IDE.

Comment: Please provide more information about the library involved. It can help.

Comment: Library is closed source third party. I've got it to give me a new error message "Can't find dependent libraries". I'll have to contact the third party to find out what those are.

Comment: According to your shots, the dll is not in the directory pointed by java.library.path, which is ext here. Note that for testing you can also copy the dll into the windows system dir.

Comment: @GuyBouallet updated to include the new error screenshot

Comment: Just fired up one of the Third Parties sample projects and Netbeans and it runs fine. Something to do with IntelliJ is my current assumption.

Comment: Alright, so if I create a new NetBeans project this works fine. Same code and everything. If I create new IntelliJ project I get this error.

Comment: As you are on windows,I guess you can see the required files in the section 2.2.1. Windows 2000/XP/Vista/7 of the document of my previous link.

Comment: @GuyBouallet, I'm including those DLL's in the directory, and if I create a project with the same source code in NetBeans I don't get any of the errors above. The project runs just fine. However if I create a project in IntelliJ with the same source code, I get dependency errors. I'm not sure if IntelliJ loads these assemblies different.

Comment: Did you make sure intellij points to the same JDK?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48721/discussion-between-will-and-guy-bouallet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obidisc4j is a .jar file. You just dont see its extension in the explorer.
Regular jar files are not loaded by System.loadLibrary. They are automatically loaded by the JVM's classLoader.

Comment: Ah I see, so this error comes from trying to load related DLL's.

Comment: Exactly. According to this document: http://www.sebeto.com/intranet/ftpscambio/RFID_FEIG/SDK/Sy%20Software%20Development%20Support/ID%20OBIDISC4J%20-%20Documentation/H31101-16e-ID-B.pdf , page 16, you should have accompagning dll or so files. Check that you have correctly installed them.

Comment: That's the interesting part. I have all the libraries listed in the same directory as the obidisc4j.dll. Not sure what else it depends on.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a native library. It doen't matter if that library is in the classpath. There are 4 ways you can make the Java runtime load your shared library at runtime:

1. Call System.load to load the .so from an explicitly specified absolute path.
2. Copy the shared library to one of the paths already listed in java.library.path
3. Modify the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to include the directory where the shared library is located.
4. Specify the java.library.path on the command line by using the -D option.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your application is trying to find out a `obidisc4j.dll` (for Windows) or `obidisc4j.so` (for Linux). The file must be present on the PATH (but not the classpath). If you are not sure what PATH is your Java application searching in, you can write the following statement, before the point where the exception takes place, to find out the PATH.

`System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));`

This will tell you about the paths where your DLL or SO file should be placed. You just need to place the file in ONE of those N-paths.